# Indy Sockets gradually slows down on hyper threaded machines

Tags: multithreading, sockets, indy, hyperthreading

This is a long shot but maybe someone has an idea. I am using IndySockets, a library that extends .Net sockets classes in a multithreaded (20-25 threads) web crawling application. The app is run on a number of different servers, some of which have hyperthreading turned on.

Using hyperthreading greatly increases the efficiency of the application (30-50% speed improvement) at first, but IndySockets calls on these machines gradually get slower and slower over a period of days. This doesn't happen on the machines that do not use hyperthreading.

To make matters even more confusing, restarting the hyperthreaded machines seems to fix the problem ie the app will run at it's initial, very fast speed again after a restart. Restarting the application does not have any effect.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am on the Indy development team.  I have not heard of any such problem when running Indy on a hyper-threaded machine.  Please use a profiler to make sure the problem really is in Indy and not elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying. We monitor the run time of many different steps of the application; the only thing that slows over time is the call to IndySockets.

Comment: What kind of calls are you making exactly?  Can you update your question to show what you are using Indy for?

Comment: We are primarily using the Get method of HttpClient, also the Head method to a much lesser degree. We are reading in the entire page contents and subsequently parsing this into the .Net XML model. The head method is occasional used to follow page redirects.

Comment: Are you making use of HTTP 1.1 keepalives?  The only threading that the HttpClient class uses internally is a worker thread needed for establishing a new connection to a server. All requests and responses go over that connection in the thread that is calling Get() and Head(), so that should not be affected by hyperthreading, unless the connection is being dropped in between each one.